# Exotic (twisted) sphere $\Sigma^n$ is homeomorpic to $S^n$ — is my proof correct?

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

For a homeomorphism $f: S^{n-1} \to S^{n-1}$ let an exotic sphere $\Sigma^n(f)$ be defined as a pushout of continuous functions $S^{n-1} \overset{f}\to S^{n-1} \hookrightarrow D^n$ and $S^{n-1} \hookrightarrow D^n$. This construction is also known as cell attachment or an adjunction space. Note, that a common way to define $S^n$ is to identify copies of $S^{n-1}$ in the disjoint union of $D^n + D^n$. I'll denote it as $D^n+D^n/\sim$.

I tried to construct a homeomorphism from $\Sigma^n(f)$ to $D^n+D^n/\sim$. Firstly, we can extend homeomorphism $f:S^{n-1} \to S^{n-1}$ to homeomorphism $F:D^n\to D^n$ using Alexander's trick. Further, let $i_{1,2}: D^n \to D^n+D^n/\sim$ be canonical inclusions. Then we can define a continuous map $\Sigma^n(f) \to D^n+D^n/\sim$ as follows: for one copy $D^n$ of the quotient space $\Sigma^n(f)$ we let the map be identical to $i_1 \circ F^{-1}$, and for the rest of the space (which is a copy of $D^n - S^{n-1}$) we let it be identical to $i_2$. We can prove that since one of the pushout maps is a closed inclusion ($S^{n-1} \hookrightarrow D^n$), then the quotient space, as a set, can be seen as a disjoint union of $D^n$ and $D^n - S^{n-1}$, so the map is well-defined. Moreover, if we look at the pushout diagram, then we can say that this map is continuous because of the universal property. Note that the first copy of $D^n$ is mapped to the one part of $D^n+D^n/\sim$ and $D^n - S^{n-1}$ is mapped to the other. This is a bijection as each of $i_1 \circ F^{-1}, i_2$ are bijections (and homeomorphism), and their codomains are disjoint. So I think I have a correct argument that shows there is a continuous bijection. A similar argument shows that there is a continuous bijection from $D^n+D^n/\sim \to \Sigma^n(f)$, where one copy of $D^n$ is mapped as $i_1 \circ F$, and the copy of $D^n-S^{n-1}$ is mapped as $i_2$. It can be seen that these two are actually inverses of each other. There is a slight imprecision in my definitions of map on quotient spaces. I say, for example, that mapping is identical to $i_1 \circ F$ on some subspace, while I should actually define it as $i_1 \circ F \circ i_1^{-1}$. Since on subspaces of interest $i_{1,2}$ are injective, this mapping is well-defined. This makes checking that bijections are inverses of each other trivial.

Is this proof correct? I would also like to know if there is a more straightforward argument that shows spaces are homeomorphic that doesn't invoke concepts more advanced than those I mentioned in my solution (e.g. compactness).